# Select not null columns as a comma separated string from dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql

I am trying to do my best to avoid using cursors. There is a comma separated list of columns in nvarchar variable that looks like this:

```
@columnList = 'col1,col2,col5'
```

There is a table with lots of varchar columns:

```
myTable: [col1],[col2],[col3],[col4],[col5],[col6],[col7]
```

This is how I select data using a dynamic sql:

```
exec ('select ' + @columnList + ' from myTable')
```

This query returns the following results:

```
[col1], [col2] , [col5]
 null , "txt1" ,  null
"txt2",  null  ,  null
 null , "txt3" , "txt4"
```

This is what I need to get:

```
@resultList = "txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4"
```

How do I select a comma separated string containing not-null values only? I know how to convert a table to comma separated string, so getting something like:

```
 [column]
  "txt1"
  "txt2"
  "txt3"
  "txt4"
```

Is also fine. Any suggestions? Feel free to suggest a basic approach, I don't expect you to write the actual code for me.

Comment: UNION ALL the non-null's to get second option.

Comment: `exec ('select ' + @columnList + ' from myTable')` is a bad idea. SQL injection is not your friend.

Comment: which sql server version?

Comment: `@columnList` is being generated on a server with another query. There is no way one can inject something in there. Feel free to suggest a better approach tho.

Comment: Mssql 2016 v13.0.x

Comment: In a nutshell, I'd recommend: 1. unpivot with cross apply 2. concatenate into comma-seperated using xml path, where is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a solution like the following, using just a [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) to create the SQL query:

```
DECLARE @columnList VARCHAR(100)
SET @columnList = 'col1,col2,col5'
SET @columnList = REPLACE(@columnList, ',', ' AS colName FROM myTable UNION ALL SELECT ');

EXEC('SELECT * FROM (SELECT ' + @columnList + ' AS colName FROM myTable)t WHERE NOT t.colName IS NULL');
```

You can also use a solution using [`UNPIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot):

```
DECLARE @columnList VARCHAR(100);
SET @columnList = 'col1,col2,col5';

EXEC('SELECT colName FROM (SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM myTable) t1 UNPIVOT (colName FOR columnNames IN (' + @columnList + ')) AS t2');
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=204f117b937b35c1d62a9065fc7ba22b)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention you already know how to aggregate into comma-seperated, here's how to unpivot your table with cross apply:

```
select unpivoted.*
from myTable
cross apply
( values
     ('col1',col2)
    ,('col2',col2)
    ,('col3',col3) -- etc
)unpivoted(colname,colval)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work for SQL Server 2017, on earlier version `STRING_AGG` usage should be replaced with [XML-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005).

You could first concatenate your results into a single line and then use `STRING_AGG` to aggregate them into a single string:

```
;with t as
(
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
   (null  , 'txt1' ,  null),
   ('txt2',  null  ,  null),
   (null  , 'txt3' , 'txt4')) x(col1, col2, col5) 
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(STUFF(CONCAT(',' + col1, ',' + col2, ',' + col5), 1, 1, ''), ',')
  FROM t
```

CTE is just for showcasing, you can simply do it in your dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @columnList NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'col1,col2,col5'
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @query = 'SELECT STRING_AGG(STUFF(CONCAT('','' + ' + REPLACE(@columnList, ',', ', '','' + ') + '), 1, 1, ''''), '','') from mytable'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

[Working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=48f49bee7cd25dd19a92ca31fe998a10)

Comment: Worth to mention, that [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) will need version 2017+. The OP stated in a comment, there's v2016 in use....

Comment: Oh right... I'm even the one to ask which version they're using exactly with `STRING_AGG` in mind, and yet I confused 2016 with 2017. I'll add a note to my answer.